# High host CPU load with KVM running Win2008R2

Tags: cpu, kvm-virtualization

Running Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS, I've created a test VM guest with Windows 2008R2 to find the most suitable settings (as I may have to switch to 2012 if configuring everything to run properly fails), and I've noticed CPU load is quite insane when the VM is on. I mean ~6-8 threads maxed kind of insane, out of 32 threads assigned to VM (16 cores with their respective HT threads, CPU configuration copied from host, and it's a xeon gold 6254), while on the guest it's only 2 threads running at ~40% load each (system process, not doing much of anything, I may try to reinstall it to get a clue if something's messed up). What can be so terribly wrong? High load appears right after windows starts loading, and is pretty constant. Also, it's a dual-socket system and both CPUs warm up, though I've set the VM to only use 1 socket in GUI (console settings were a bit overwhelming to start from).

I'd generally be glad to receive help on setting up Ubuntu as a hypervisor for a Windows terminal server (a number of them, later on). Couldn't set up SR-IOV VFs to create on boot, either (yes I know it shouln't work with windows 2008, but I had to try).

Tell me what information on system to add, and I'll post it here

Comment: Just BTW: [Windows 2008 Server is EOL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2008).

Comment: I know, but I'd rather use OS that is tried and tested with our software.